# Visual Studio 2013 "embed interopt type" error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am facing problem with huge amount of errors in visual studio, that is caused by unknown problem.
I don't know, how and where I could but the embed interopt type to false.

[image: Errors that I have with VS2013]

Last time I resolved this problem with uninstalling my Visual Studio and all related programs, but this time it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have your project setup wrong, not a problem you can fix by re-installing Visual Studio.  Never use that crutch btw.  You added more than one reference for PowerPoint, incompatible versions as well.  You picked Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint, a PIA, which got you the reference to the Office 2010 version, and you picked "Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library" from the COM tab, the Office 2013 version.

You can't have it both ways, you can only target one specific version of Office.

One possible reason you got into trouble is because Microsoft no longer publishes the PIAs for new Office versions, starting with Office 2013.  PIAs are obsolete, elegantly and efficiently replaced by the "Embed Interop Types" option available since .NET 4.0 and VS2010.  Also known as the "No PIA" feature.

You have to pick one or the other, both cannot work.  If you intentionally want to target an old Office version then using the PIA is the right way.  But strongly favor the COM tab reference, it ensures that you'll test your program with the Office version you have on your machine and avoids the need to have the PIA installed on the user's machine.